# Laravel 6 - How to create a table with dynamic rows using LaravelCollective?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-6, laravelcollective

I want to make a dynamic table using `LaravelCollective`, where you can add/remove rows.

I already tried to follow a few tutorials, but I keep failing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Html Code for the table/form**

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'TransactionsINController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}
<section>
    <div class="panel panel-header">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('supplier_name', 'Supplier Name') }}
            {{ Form::select('supplier_name', $supplierList->pluck('name', 'id'), 
            null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pick one supplier...']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('transaction_in_date', 'Transcation Date') }} <br>
            {{ Form::date('transaction_in_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d M Y')) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-footer">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="">
            <thead align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>Device Type</th>
                    <th>Spec</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th><a href="#" class="btn btn-success addRow">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ Form::select('device_type_name[]', $deviceTypeList->pluck('name_tipe_device', 'id'), 
                            null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pick Device Type...', 'name' => 'device_type_name[]']) }}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ Form::textarea('device_spec[]', '', 
                            ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Device Spec', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 45, 'name' => 'device_spec[]']) }}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ Form::number('device_price[]', 'value', ['name' => 'device_price[]']) }}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
{{ Form::button('<i class="far fa-save"></i> Submit', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-info'] )  }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**The Script i use to add/remove Rows**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.addRow').on('click', function(){      \\Uncaught ReferenceError: happen in this line.
            addRow();
        });

        function addRow(){
            var tr = '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '{{ Form::select('device_type_name[]', $deviceTypeList->pluck('nama_tipe_device', 'id'),
                        null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pick Device Type...', 'name' => 'device_type_name[]']) }}'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</td>'+
                '<td>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '{{ Form::textarea('device_spec[]', '',
                        ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Device Spec', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 45, 'name' => 'device_spec[]']) }}'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</td>'+
                '<td>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '{{ Form::number('device_price[]', 'value', ['name' => 'device_price[]']) }}'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</td>'+
                '<td>'+
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">'+
                        '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'+
                    '</a>'+
                '</td>'+
            '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(tr);
        }
    </script>
```

When I press the `+` button to add more rows it doesn't do anything and when I inspected the code in the browser, I found this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: have you included JQuery file before use this syntax?

Comment: @HH thanks i just did add the `jquery` to this `blade` directly, i don't understand i already put `jquery` in my `sidebar.blade.app`, which the sidebar i use for this `blade` why i need to write it again in this `blade`. I though the `jquery` in `sidebar.blade.app` is for every `blade` as long as they use the `sidebar`.

Comment: @Aditya jQuery may not have loaded when that script runs, you can try wrapping your script with `$(document).ready({  })` so it runs it when jQuery has loaded

Comment: @Aditya did this work for you?

Comment: @HH yep its working now, just add the cdn on the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` refers to jQuery, have you added it to your project and is it available in this scope?

**Note:** it needs to be present before your script

jQuery may not have loaded when that script runs, you can try wrapping your script with `$(document).ready({ })` so it runs it when jQuery has loaded